# Deserlize BSON into objects in client from WebAPI

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, bson

I have a web API that is currently returning a BSON response from a POST.

Normally I have the WebAPI returning JSON and I just do this in the client to deserialize it into my C# object or objects.

```
var result = await GetApiClient().PostAsJsonAsync("api/Test/GetImages", args);

if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     return await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
```

I am now doing this to get the BSON response:

```
MediaTypeFormatter bsonFormatter = new BsonMediaTypeFormatter();
var result = await GetApiClient().PostAsync("api/Test/GetImages", args, bsonFormatter);

    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         return await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
```

The JSON works fine, but the BSON errors when reading the content:

```
No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type IEnumerable1 from content with media type 'application/bson'
```

I am 100% certain I am getting BSON back, I am just not sure how to deserialize it into objects now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured this out, I needed to include the formatter in the ReadAsAsync call. Much simpler than I anticipated

```
ReadAsAsync<T>(new List<MediaTypeFormatter>() {bsonFormatter})
```